# Understanding time complexity of matrix solution

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, time-complexity

Worked on an algorithm that requires counting the longest number of contiguous 1's in a matrix. The provided solution description and solution is as follows:

> The brute force approach is really simple. We directly traverse along
>   every valid line in the given matrix: i.e. Horizontal, Vertical,
>   Diagonal aline above and below the middle diagonal, Anti-diagonal line
>   above and below the middle anti-diagonal. Each time during the
>   traversal, we keep on incrementing the countcount if we encounter
>   continuous 1's. We reset the countcount for any discontinuity
>   encountered. While doing this, we also keep a track of the maximum
>   count found so far.

```
public class Solution {
    public int longestLine(int[][] M) {
        if (M.length == 0)
            return 0;
        int ones = 0;
        //horizontal
        for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < M[0].length; j++) {
                if (M[i][j] == 1) {
                    count++;
                    ones = Math.max(ones, count);
                } else
                    count = 0;
            }
        }
        //vertical
        for (int i = 0; i < M[0].length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < M.length; j++) {
                if (M[j][i] == 1) {
                    count++;
                    ones = Math.max(ones, count);
                } else
                    count = 0;
            }
        }
        //upper diagonal
        for (int i = 0; i < M[0].length || i < M.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = 0, y = i; x < M.length && y < M[0].length; x++, y++) {
                if (M[x][y] == 1) {
                    count++;
                    ones = Math.max(ones, count);
                } else
                    count = 0;
            }
        }
        //lower diagonal
        for (int i = 0; i < M[0].length || i < M.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = i, y = 0; x < M.length && y < M[0].length; x++, y++) {
                if (M[x][y] == 1) {
                    count++;
                    ones = Math.max(ones, count);
                } else
                    count = 0;
            }
        }
        //upper anti-diagonal
        for (int i = 0; i < M[0].length || i < M.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = 0, y = M[0].length - i - 1; x < M.length && y >= 0; x++, y--) {
                if (M[x][y] == 1) {
                    count++;
                    ones = Math.max(ones, count);
                } else
                    count = 0;
            }
        }
        //lower anti-diagonal
        for (int i = 0; i < M[0].length || i < M.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = i, y = M[0].length - 1; x < M.length && y >= 0; x++, y--) {
                //System.out.println(x+" "+y);
                if (M[x][y] == 1) {
                    count++;
                    ones = Math.max(ones, count);
                } else
                    count = 0;
            }
        }
        return ones;

    }
}
```

Complexity Analysis

Time complexity : O(n^2)
We traverse along the entire matrix 4 times.
Space complexity : O(1). Constant space is used.

If we simply traverse through the matrix for every row & col, then we know that it's not a quadratic algorithm. Does the quadratic work happen because elements are touched N times per diagonal?

Comment: what does "If we simply traverse through the matrix for every row & col, then we know that it's not a quadratic algorithm." mean? Quadratic in what?
 If you traverse through each row, that is quadratic in the side length. Is n the length of the side or the number of elements in the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

What is `n`?

Is the matrix a square?
If yes, then `n` is width/height of matrix.
If no, then you need `m` and `n`, representing width and height independently.

Lets say it's not square.

If you double the width (`m`), what happens in the code?
The total number of iterations double, so performance is linear to `m`.

If you double the height (`n`), what happens in the code?
The total number of iterations double, so performance is linear to `n`.

Conclusion: Performance is *O(mn)*

---

Of course, if `n` is number of values in matrix, performance is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that there are n² elements, not n.

The algorithm visits each element a finite number of times. So one can say that it is linear in the number of elements, thus quadratic in n.

Comment: That seems like bad notation then-- if count of rows = M and count of cols = N, and the solution says O(N^2)--you're right that this is where I was confused. I just didn't expect solutions to be incorrect with notation

Comment: This is not "bad" notation, you just have to be clear about the meaning of the parameters.